# AngularJS $setViewValue() Not Responding in $parsers.push()

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive.  It requires `ngModel`, and in the link, I should be able to use `modelCtrl` parameter to use `$setViewValue();` and `$render();` in conjunction to return to change the value in my input field and update the value stored in `ngModel`.  Unfortunately, when I pass `modelCtrl` into my logic function, I cannot use `$setViewValue();` and `$render();`, even though I pass `modelCtrl` to the function.  (See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GSTC5/1/)

```
myApp.directive('demo', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'EACM',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            setAndRender(modelCtrl, "12345");
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
                return logic(inputValue, modelCtrl);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I have something very similar working in another directive I wrote, why is it failing here?

**UPDATE**
I believe that the fault lies with `$setViewValue()`.  I know it responds when it is called from the link function, but `$setViewValue` stops the code from running when it is called from the logic function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$setViewValue is called from the logic method, which triggers another $parsers cycle, creating infinite recursion causing the `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

ngModelController.**$parsers[]** affect the resulting ngModelController.**$modelValue**, if you also want to affect the ngModelController.**$viewValue**, you can set the $viewValue directly and call ngModelController.**$render()** to allow the component to update the DOM.

http://jsfiddle.net/GSTC5/4/

The ngModelController.**$setViewValue()** should only be called by the DOM change event.

This should've been a job for the ngModelController.$formatters[], but sadly the formatters aren't applied when the change is initiated by $setViewValue()

Comment: Is there something I can use to prevent the infinite recursion, or something that I can replace the $setViewValue() call with?